# How to check if a specific time is between to dates?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to create a function that checks, if a specific time is between two timestamps that are stored in a MySQL database.

The function should be able to ignore the time (`$fullday = true`) or check the time as well.

My presence table has a row with `start = 2021-11-01 10:00:00` and `end = 2021-11-05 18:00:00`.

`is_available('2021-11-02', true);` should give me a result, but is doesn't.

What I expect as well:

`is_available('2021-11-01 09:30:00');` should not have a result, as 9:30 is before 10:00 but `is_available('2021-11-01 10:01:00');` should give me a result. And so on.

The query, my function creates is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `presence`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start, "%Y-%m-%d") <= "2021-11-02"
AND DATE_FORMAT(end, "%Y-%m-%d") >= "2021-11-02"
```

And this my function so far:

```php
function is_available($date, $fullday = false)
{
    $presenceModel = new PresenceModel();

    if ($fullday) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
        $presences = $presenceModel
            ->where('DATE_FORMAT(start, "%Y-%m-%d") <= "' . $date . '"')
            ->where('DATE_FORMAT(end, "%Y-%m-%d") >= "' . $date . '"')
            ->findAll();
    } else {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
        $presences = $presenceModel
            ->where('DATE_FORMAT(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") <= "' . $date . '"')
            ->where('DATE_FORMAT(end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") >= "' . $date . '"')
            ->findAll();
    }

    return count($presences) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your query in Database directly? Does it work? Also can you debug php model select to be sure that it is formed correctly as you expect? Try to get sql and run it in db directly

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using `BETWEEN`, as in `SELECT *
  FROM presence
  WHERE  "2021-11-02" BETWEEN start AND end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify this dramatically by getting MySQl to do more of the work. You don't need to format DATETIME columns to do comparisons on them, and BETWEEN will further reduce your PHP effort.

Based on your code above I think this will do the job:

```
function is_available($date, $fullDay = false) {
    $presenceModel = new PresenceModel();
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

    if ($fullDay) {
        $presences = $presenceModel
            ->where("'$date' between DATE(`start`) and DATE(`end`)" )
            ->findAll();
    } else {
        $presences = $presenceModel
            ->where("'$date' between `start` and `end`" )
            ->findAll();
    }
    return count($presences) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

However, using `SELECT *` will return the entirety of all the matching rows, when all you really need is whether one exists. You should aim to get your query something close to this, which will return just a single value (`1`) if there's a matching row.:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `presence`
  WHERE "2021-11-02" between start AND end 
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the limitation with `SELECT 1`. But.. your example doesn't return something for `is_available("2021-11-01 09:30:00");` but it should, as it should ignore the time.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to change `->where("'$date' between start and end" )` to `->where("DATE('$date') between DATE(start) and DATE(end)")`

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use `strtotime()` function to convert the date into an **int** and then convert the other date from the **db** and then compare those **ints** in php.

```
if($datenow > $dbstartdate && $datenow < $dbenddate){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```